# Is multiplication an operation in the given set of matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let $$ G = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}
        (-1)^{a} & a \\
        0 & (-1)^{a}\\
        \end{bmatrix}: a\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$ be a set of matrices. Is multiplication an operation within this set?

I know I have to multiply any two matrices of the form from the set and the result has to be of the same form. I get
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        (-1)^{b+c} & (-1)^{b}\cdot c +b\cdot(-1)^{c} \\
        0 & (-1)^{b+c}\\
        \end{bmatrix},$$
so $b+c$ is supposed to equal $(-1)^{b}\cdot c +b\cdot(-1)^{c}$, which is not true for $b=4$ and $c=5$, for example. Thus in my opinion multiplication is not an operation within the set, but as far as I know the correct answer is the opposite. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: When you say you want to prove that "multiplication is an operation within the set" do you mean you want to prove whether the set is closed under this operation?

Comment: @Arthur I want to prove the basic condition for G to be a group, so the result of the operation has to be in G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix} (-1)^{b+c} & (-1)^{b}\cdot c +b\cdot(-1)^{c} \\  0 & (-1)^{b+c} \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{cases}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c +b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, & \text{if } b \text{ and } c\text{ are even,} \\[10pt]
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & c - b \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, & \text{if } c \text{ is even and } b \text{ is odd,}  \\[10pt]
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & b-c \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}, & \text{if }c \text{ is odd and } b \text{ is even,} \\[10pt]
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -b-c \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, & \text{if } b \text{ and } c \text{ are odd.}
\end{cases}
$$
In every case we get either $1$ or $-1$ in each diagonal position and an integer in the upper right, and in every case you get $+1$ if the number in the upper right is even and $-1$ if it's odd. **Thus this set of matrices is closed under multiplication. However,** addition of integers in the expression $b+c$ does not correspond to matrix multiplication, so the mapping is not a homomorphism (let alone an isomorphism) from $\mathbb Z$ into this set of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct since $(-1)^1=(-1)^{(-1)}=-1$ then  $$(-1)^{(-1)^b}=(-1)^{(-1)^c}=-1$$ (because $(-1)^b=(-1)^{-b}$ and $(-1)^c=(-1)^{-c}$ and all are  $1$ or $-1$) ,  then:  $$(-1)^{c.(-1)^b}=(-1)^c  \; \text{and} \;  (-1)^{b.(-1)^c}=(-1)^b.$$

It's not necessary to have $b+c=(-1)^b.c+(-1)^c.b$ (for example $(-1)5=(-1)^{11}$ but  $5 \neq 11$.)

If we put $d=(-1)^b.c+(-1)^c.b$, then your  product is: $$\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^d&d\\0&(-1)^d\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in your reasoning is in the fact that you assumed that we have to have that $b+c=(-1)^bc+(-1)^cb$, when actually we have to have that $(-1)^{b+c}=(-1)^{(-1)^bc+(-1)^cb}$, which is easy to prove:
$$(-1)^{(-1)^bc+(-1)^cb}=(-1)^{(-1)^bc}(-1)^{(-1)^cb}=((-1)^{(-1)^b})^c((-1)^{(-1)^c})^b=(-1)^c(-1)^b$$

Comment: Do you understand why?

Comment: @ Arthur It is still somewhat unclear to me.

Comment: For example, take the matrix whose entries are:$$a_{11}=(-1)^3, a_{21}=0,a_{12}=5,a_{22}=(-1)^3$$

Comment: Shouldn't $a_{11}$ be the same as $a_{22}$?

Comment: Even though $3\neq5$, the matrix is still in the considered set

Comment: And they are! Even though I first typed (I just edited) in $a_{11}=(-1)^3, a_{22}=(-1)^5$, they are still the same

Comment: Did you understand now, @Theta?

Comment: But I meant: shouldn't there be one particular $a$ for some chosen element of $G$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47427/discussion-between-arthur-and-theta).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use your suggestion
$$\begin{pmatrix} (-1)^4&4\\0&(-1)^4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} (-1)^5&5\\0&(-1)^5\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix} 1&4\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -1&5\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix} -1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

So we see that the final matrix is of the form required.

EDIT:
NOT A GROUP!

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} -1&1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and recall that if 
$B = \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ then $B^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(B)}\begin{pmatrix} d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$ so it can easily be seen that $A^{-1} =\begin{pmatrix} -1&-1\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} $ which is not the required form! So this is not a group.... however, it is closed under the operation so it is a groupoid.

Comment: This does work out but you have not shown it for general parities of $b$ and $c$.  Also, if he wanted a group to be formed, that won't happen becase the inverses are not in the set.

Comment: Yes I'm aware.... however he said that this "is not true for $b=4$ and $c=5$".  I was really just trying to show him that.....  I was going to give a more detailed answer, then I got distracted by a phone call and pretty soon there are other good answers... but his first calculation seemed off so I thought he might want to know

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my edit reflects your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Take two cases

When $a=2n+1$ is odd  the matrix looks like $$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2n+1 \\ 0 &  -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

When $a=2n$ is even $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2n \\ 0 &  1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So there are only four possibilities. For example,
$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2n+1 \\ 0 &  -1 \end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2m+1 \\ 0 &  -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2(-n-m-1) \\ 0 &  1 \end{pmatrix}$$
 So again it belongs to the set.

Similarly work out the other case. This shows this set is closed that under the multiplication operation.

Comment: @theta Does it clarify ?

Comment: It does, thank you, I failed to make this observation and still doubt I would have come up with such an approach myself.